# MYSQL Query with String Refer to Value in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have MYSQL query like the below:

```
$sourcedata = mysql_fetch_array(
                mysql_query("SELECT Whereclause 
                               FROM generaltable 
                              WHERE ID = '1'"
                           )
                );

$Whereclause = $sourcedata['Whereclause'];
```

In "Whereclause" field from "generaltable" in database, consist of the below text:

```
WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'
```

Then I have other query:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array(
                   mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                  FROM usertable 
                                       $Whereclause"
                              )
                        );
```

When I `echo $data['username'],` it is not showing anything.

If I copy the value from database to replace $Whereclause it is working fine, also if I replace '$_SESSION[username]' with 'admin' for example, it is working fine.

How can I solve this? Need your help please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: try to print "SELECT * FROM usertable $Whereclause" and query it in your mysql editor

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 yes, I put that value in database field.

Comment: @Pantamtuy Do you mean from sql query in phpmyadmin? Can it identify the $Whereclause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `$Whereclause` is a String, so it is not evaluated (`'$_SESSION[username]'` remains exactly as it is).

You have to tell PHP to evaluate this string with the function  [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array(
          mysql_query(
           eval("return \"SELECT * FROM usertable $Whereclause\";")
         )
        );
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

Comment: True! I'm going to correct it, look back the answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

As you are using fetch array. Can you please try with

```
$data[0]['username']
```